# Sequential Promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, request-promise

so I am trying to execute my promises sequentially without using async below is my code

```
//promises is an array of function who return a promise
const p = function(promises){
    let result = promises.reduce((prevPromise, promise) => {
        return prevPromise.then(res => {
            return promise.then(Array.prototype.concat.bind(res))
        })
    }, Promise.resolve([]));
    return result;
}
```

now say promises array has 2 functions which execute in 5 and 10 secs respectively, above code is giving answer in 10 secs but if true sequence execution should give in 15 secs. Please suggest.

Comment: What's wrong with `async`/`await`?

Comment: If you already have an array of promises, the only thing you can do is to wait for them (using `Promise.all`). If you want stuff to execute sequentially, that means you need **functions** that you can **call** sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion. `promises.reduce` just chained the promise but did not delay the perform time.

The promise perform time is when you create `new Promise()`

Create new promise in your `then` statement.

Comment: There are many reasons not to use the Promise constructor unnecessarily, but I doubt the performance impact is significant

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are reducing an array of promises instead of an execution of an asynchronous operations that returns a promise.

Take the example below, where we have a `delay()` function that returns a promise, performing an asynchronous `setTimeout()` operation where it resolves the `ms` delay after the timeout.

```js
// a function that returns a promise that will only resolve
// after the setTimeout has finished.
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(
  resolve,
  ms,
  ms
));

// array of milliseconds to execute the delay() function
const items = [5000, 10000];

// timer to track the amount of time 
// passed after all delays are executed
console.time('delay');

// Reducing all promises wherein items are the delayed timeout
// while also the items that will be added in this reduction
const promise = items.reduce((promise, value) =>
  // wait for promise to resolve
  promise.then(result => 
    // perform async operation
    delay(value)
      // add each resolved value
      .then(item => result + item)
  ),
  // default value of reduction
  Promise.resolve(0)
);

promise.then(result => {
  // Should be the summation of the items array
  console.log('result', result);
  // show the time tracker if all of these operations
  // really finished appropriately.
  console.timeEnd('delay');
});
```